# Can't use global variable in group expression

Tags: reporting-services

I want to use Globals!RenderFormat.Name to conditional group expression. but the error was occured like this when i try to preview

```
"The groupexpression for the tablix "..." refers to the global variable RenderFormat, which is not valid for this type of report item expression."
```

I also try to use just "=Globals!RenderFormat.Name" in group expression but result was the same.

How can i use "Globals!RenderFormat.Name" in group expression?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="X",1,0)

Comment: This seems like its critical if trying to unmerge grouped cells when exporting to Excel. An answer would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Globals!RenderFormat.Name` in group expressions.
A possible workaround is to add a second tablix without grouping to show if `lcase(left(Globals!RenderFormat.Name,5))="excel"` (could also be `EXCELOPENXML`) and hide the orginal one if it is an excel export and vice versa